# How can I create identical cron jobs for staging and production with the whenever gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I have one job in `schedule.rb`:

```rb
set :output, File.expand_path('../log/whenever.log', __FILE__)
set :job_template, "bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc ; :job'"

every 1.day, :at => '12:01 am' do
  runner "MyModel.do_something"
end
```

In my staging deployment (bash) script I have this line to write to cron:

```bsh
ssh $SERVER "cd $DEPLOY_TO && whenever --set environment=staging -w"
```

And this line in the production deployment script:

```bsh
ssh $SERVER "cd $DEPLOY_TO && whenever --set environment=production -w"
```

This works fine and creates the job when I deploy either environment. The problem is that whenever sees them both as one job so it gets overwritten by whichever environment was last deployed:

```bsh
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/simon/apps/myapp/staging/config/schedule.rb
1 0 * * * bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc ; cd /Users/simon/apps/myapp/staging && script/rails runner -e staging 'MyModel.do_something' >> /Users/simon/apps/myapp/staging/log/whenever.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/simon/apps/myapp/staging/config/schedule.rb
```

and...

```bsh
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/simon/apps/myapp/production/config/schedule.rb
1 0 * * * bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc ; cd /Users/simon/apps/myapp/production && script/rails runner -e production 'MyModel.do_something' >> /Users/simon/apps/myapp/production/log/whenever.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/simon/apps/myapp/production/config/schedule.rb
```

What's a sensible way to add the same cron job for two separate environments on the same server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can namespace your whenever tasks by using something similar to the following:

```
# Whenever
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
set :whenever_identifier, defer { "#{application}-#{stage}" }
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

In the above example, `stage` is the variable that contains the environment. Change it to whatever you are using.

The **Capistrano integration** section at https://github.com/javan/whenever goes into a bit more detail if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

For **capistrano-v3-integration**  add `require "whenever/capistrano"` to `Capfile` and set `set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }` to `config/deploy.rb`

- [capistrano-v3-integration](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-v3-integration)